# Manually updating Symfony2 deps file to get Doctrine 2.2?

Tags: symfony, pagination, doctrine-orm

Is possible to manually update `deps` file to get the latest version of **Doctrine 2.2**? I'd like to use the new [Paginator](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html?highlight=pagination) component. So basically i was thinking to tweak `deps` with:

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.2.1
```

Remove `deps.lock` and do:

```
php bin/vendors update
```

**Do you think that will work?**

**EDIT**: the file would look like this: http://pastebin.com/FEDMNhii

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, all of the work suggested by [gilden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740201/3765) is unnecessary and over-cautious. Of course you can manually update your `deps` file with whatever you want. I'm currently running Doctrine\Common (2.2.1), Doctrine\DBAL (2.2.1), and Doctrine (2.2.1) on Symfony 2.0.11 without issues.

It isn't the libraries that you need to worry about (usually), it is the **bundles** that *utilize* the libraries that require specific version(s). For example, Symfony2 has no direct dependency on any version of Doctrine -- but the [DoctrineBundle](http://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-bundle) does.

Before upgrading a bundle/library, it is usually good to check out their required dependencies on [Packagist.org](http://packagist.org). Search for the package you want to upgrade and see what required dependencies they define. **Note:** This won't be required on Symfony 2.1 since it will use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) to manage vendor libraries.

Although, you'll never know if something works with your install or not unless you try it. Of course, don't do anything stupid - but there is no reason to be scared of breaking things by updating vendor libraries. Store your code in Git and you can easily revert your changes. See: [How to create and store a Symfony2 project in Git](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html)

---

Also, when specifying `version=#.#.#` in `deps` - even if you do not have a `deps.lock` file at all, you will always get the same commit hash because you are specifying the Git tag on the repository.

Some bundles, rather than providing version numbers, will offer various branches for managing compatibility with multiple Symfony versions. So you may see something like `version=origin/2.0` which means the vendors script will checkout the latest commit on the branch named `2.0` of the repository. The maintainer will most likely try to keep that branch always compatible with Symfony 2.0.x.

Comment: So good explanation, +1. Btw, when Symfony 2.1 will be available?

Answer (score -1):

By removing the `deps.lock` file you're obviously putting yourself at risk to getting unstable code.

I have used the following steps to minimize the risk of breaking something:

- Write down the current commit hash of the components you'd like to update from `deps.lock`
- Find the commit hash from GitHub and write it down.
- Navigate to a component's directory and type `git checkout [commit]` where [commit] is the new hash.
- Clear your cache and verify that the site is still more or less working.
- Paste the new commit hash to `deps.lock` and run `bin/vendors install`

Keep in mind that I would strongly advise against this. Should you screw things up, you're pretty much on your own and there's no-one to help you.

Comment: Thank you man. I did a quick test on a fresh install and all seems fine (entity generation, queries and so on). But again thanks for the advice.

Comment: why not simply save deps and deps.lock (or using git) and in case something breaks you revert your changes and update your vendors again. It should download everything as specified in the deps.lock?

Comment: I agree that this advice seems to be overly cautious and complicated when the deps.lock can be saved and restored in the case of disaster.

Comment: @Boo, @user1207727 - I have at least 2 very good reasons in my opinion: 1) I want to keep my git log clean; 2) if I'm trying to find stable versions, I might need to do the process several times. With the method above I will save some time compared to running `bin\vendors install` several times.

Comment: @gilden You can keep your git log clean by using the branching, `git commit --amend` and `git rebase` features of git.