# What version of doctrine-mongodb-odm should I use with Symfony2 v2.0.12?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.0

After some trial and error (ok, just error) I figured out that [c089b69c3d](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/commit/c089b69c3d9496797747cd78d2ecc4c1eeaf4a25) contained something that broke my code, causing

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy' not found
```

but [the commit before that](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/commit/318348e15acee8250ef6f83a9a8b2cf9cf6a4114) worked.

Is there any general recommendation of which version of doctrine-mongodb-odm should be used with the Symfony2 standard distribution v2.0.12?

Comment: @elnur, you might want to review [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137230/135887) [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138683/135887) Meta discussions about symfony tagging.

Comment: @Charles, you might want to read my answer to the first discussion, comments to it and the [chat log](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/16862/2012/9/19) that took place before we called for moderator attention. ;)

Comment: I'm tagging this question with [symfony-2.0] because it's 2.0 specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `deps` and `deps.lock` files for any version fixes on doctrine-common.

The doctrine-mongodb master branch sub-modules doctrine-common at commit [fc26d10](https://github.com/doctrine/common/tree/fc26d10d97dc773923a8d561e9301c3c73b9cc70)

See https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/tree/master/lib/vendor.

Also see this question and answer for more information - [Manually updating Symfony2 deps file to get Doctrine 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739350/manually-updating-symfony2-deps-file-to-get-doctrine-2-2)

Comment: Thanks @Phil! You were spot on. Turns out it was actually my copy of symfony (installed in `vendor/symfony`) that was [inappropriately pegged](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/symfony2/jkUMRFTHtzw/discussion).

Answer (score 0):

add in your `deps.lock`:

```
doctrine-mongodb-odm 2239012af4d7f9954898068e8458d7e1a0f6143f
```

Comment: I've got mine pegged at bd65a47c32f9ad9ac888914ab88d89976a5bcfe8. Should I go with 2239012af4d7f9954898068e8458d7e1a0f6143f instead? Why?

Comment: You shouldn't write anything to `deps.lock` as it's a generated file!